# React setInterval via Hook - Invalid hook call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to perform an action periodically (always after 4 seconds).

I have taken this as example: https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/

Problem:

***Uncaught Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app***

I know that React Hooks can only be used in the main context and not in sub-contexts. And exactly this is my problem here. I want to use a function to create my interval.

Maybe there is a complete different approach.

That's what I have so far, can someone help?

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { List } from 'antd';
import axios from 'axios';
import isRequestPerformOk from '../../utils/isRequestPerformOk';
import assertChain from '../../utils/assertChain';
import getConfigs from '../../utils/getConfigs';

const useInterval = (callback, delay) => {
  const savedCallback = useRef();

  // Remember the latest function.
  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  // Set up the interval.
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current();
    }
    if (delay !== null) {
      const id = setInterval(tick, delay);
      return () => clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, [delay]);
};

const T3nNews = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({ entries: [] });
  const configs = getConfigs();

  const updateDataFn = async (uri) => {
    const res = await axios.get(uri);
    const entriesList = assertChain(res, 'data.entries')
      ? res.data.entries
      : [];
    setData({ entries: entriesList });
  };

  const setUpDataFn = (uri) => {
    useInterval(() => {
      if (isRequestPerformOk() || true) {
        updateDataFn(uri);
      }
    }, 4000);
    updateDataFn(uri);
  };

  setUpDataFn(configs.uris.t3nRSS);

  const createMarkup = description => ({ __html: description });
  return (
    <List
      className="t3nNews"
      itemLayout="horizontal"
      dataSource={data.entries}
      renderItem={item => (
        <List.Item>
          <List.Item.Meta
            className="meta"
            title={item.title}
            description={
              <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(item.description)} />
            }
          />
        </List.Item>
      )}
    />
  );
};
export default T3nNews;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `useEffect` **inside another** `useEffect` when calling `useInterval(...)`, which is forbidden.

Most likely, this is what you want instead:

```
const T3nNews = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({ entries: [] });
  const configs = getConfigs();

  const updateDataFn = async (uri) => {
    const res = await axios.get(uri);
    const entriesList = assertChain(res, 'data.entries')
      ? res.data.entries
      : [];
    setData({ entries: entriesList });
  };

  useInterval(() => {
    if (isRequestPerformOk() || true) {
      updateDataFn(configs.uris.t3nRSS);
    }
  }, 4000);

  const createMarkup = description => ({ __html: description });
  return (
    <List
      className="t3nNews"
      itemLayout="horizontal"
      dataSource={data.entries}
      renderItem={item => (
        <List.Item>
          <List.Item.Meta
            className="meta"
            title={item.title}
            description={
              <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(item.description)} />
            }
          />
        </List.Item>
      )}
    />
  );
};
```

Note: `useInterval` should be defined outside of the component, to avoid recreating the hook every render (but that's not the issue).

Comment: Hi @Matthieu Libeer, I did that now but gives me the same error. I edited the code in my initial post. May you have a look again?

Comment: Did you notice that I removed the call to `useEffect`, and now only call `useInterval`?

Comment: I will need that useEffect in either way, because I also need to handle the componentWillUnmount() equivalent later on..

Comment: You can have another useEffect next to `useInterval`, however you cannot have the `useInterval` inside the `useEffect`. This is the source of your issue.

Comment: Well but how to solve my problem then ? I want to start that setInterval if the component has mounted, therefor I need to put it in useEffect. No idea how to solve it with react hooks then.. How can I get this run without putting the useInterval inside of the useEffect?

Comment: You can do `setUpDataFn(configs.uris.t3nRSS);`

instead of `useEffect(() => { setUpDataFn(configs.uris.t3nRSS); });`

No need to add the `useEffect` yourself, `useInterval` already sets up the interval on mount.

Comment: Ok, thanks. The code runs now, but the function is called immediately. It does not wait for 4000 milliseconds. What's the reason for that? See my initial post.

Comment: You're calling `updateDataFn(uri);` after `useInterval`. Remove it and you should be good

Comment: Interesting, why does this happen? But solves the problem. Thank you very much, will definitely accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your hook definition looks fine, but you can't define a custom hook from within a component. If you look at the [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/105x531vkq) from the article, you can see the hook is defined outside.

Just move the `useInterval` definition outside the `T3nNews` component and it'll work (and you'll be able to use it in other components!).

Comment: Hi vinsanity555, I did that now but gives me the same error. I edited the code in my initial post. May you have a look again?